# What to do after submiting a archive to iTunes connect?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I just submitted my first ever Xcode project. The upload is done and it worked perfectly, but what do I do next?

Apple didn't tell me what to do or how much time to wait now.

Comment: Read the [Submitting the App to App Review](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW1) section of the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/About.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH1-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

1. After upload successfully go to your itunes account select build and submit it for review
2. Wait for 6-7 days. May be it takes more time than it. They will send mail to you when your app is in review.
3. They also send the ans of review of your application.